# Jenkins docker image throwing error while pulling

Tags: docker, jenkins, putty

I have created SSH connect on PuTTY for CentOS 7 running on Oracle VM Virtualbox.
On PuTTy, I have installed Docker, followed by Docker Compose and they are up and running.
However, I am encountering error when i tried to download the Jenkins Docker Image found on https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/ using:

```
[jenkins@localhost ~]$ docker pull jenkins/jenkins
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/jenkins/jenkins/manifests/latest: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Ajenkins%2Fjenkins%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Also tried:

```
[jenkins@localhost ~]$  docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

My internet connection is working perfectly fine.
Any leads to resolve this issue.? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging out first and login using the username instead of email.

[Github Issues](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2640#issuecomment-370149492)

Comment: Xeros007, I still dont know but somehow this worked after trying logging in and out couple of times. Before posting the question also, I tried logging in and out once, but earlier it dint worked, but somehow its working now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not logged in to your docker hub account on your terminal.
use the command `docker login --username=yourhubusername --email=youremail@company.com` To log in.

And then try the pull command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, since the account is not linked to any email ID, I tried: docker login --username=myhubusername, but received same error: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers); However, when i a trying "sudo systemctl start docker" this command dint throw any error for starting docker

Comment: Moreover, sudo docker run hello-world command is running fine, which means docker is up and running correctly.